# AccessDeniedException when writing into JCR (JackRabbit) [Magnolia]

Tags: jcr, magnolia

I wrote a request filter for geoIP localization. It works the way that I request an external service for the localization and then write the information into JCR, into a dedicated workspace for caching/storage.

On the author instance this works, but on the public instance I constantly get a AccessDeniedException. I probably need to authenticate with the JCR, and I tried that too, using the crendentials from the magnolia.properties file:

```
magnolia.connection.jcr.userId = username
magnolia.connection.jcr.password = password
```

And this code for authentication:

```
Session session = MgnlContext.getJCRSession(WORKSPACE_IP_ADDRESSES);
session.impersonate(new SimpleCredentials("username", "password".toCharArray()));
```

I have the [this xml](http://pastebin.com/cQ6RURbZ) to bootstrap the filter, and a FilterOrdering Task, configured as follows:

```
tasks.add(new FilterOrderingTask("geoIp", new String[] { "contentType", "login", "logout", "csrfSecurity",
            "range", "cache", "virtualURI" }));
```

What am I missing?

What would be the proper to write into the JCR in Magnolia on the public instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, that could not work :D

Is your filter configured in Magnolia's filter chain or directly in `web.xml`? It needs to live in filter chain and it needs to be configured somewhere down the chain after the security filters so that user is already authenticated.
Then you can simply call `MgnlContext.getJCRSession("workspace_name")` to get access to repo and do whatever you need.

HTH,
Jan

Comment: I have the filter configured in the filter chain, I added some more info in the question. I also redeployed everything from start and saw the the filter ordering has failed `info.magnolia.module.InstallContextImpl           : > Could not sort filter geoIp. It should be positioned after [contentType, login, logout, csrfSecurity, range, cache, virtualURI]
`.

Comment: Hi Jan, I configured the filter that it now comes after the servlet filter, so after the securityCallback filter which is responsible for AccessDenied, according to the docs. On my public instance it still does not work, I still get an AccessDeniedException.

Comment: Or it the public instance not allowed to write at all?

Comment: no, as anonymous user you are not allowed to write. Either you authenticate user or you will need to execute your write in system context like `MgnlContext.doInSystemContext(new Op(){...})` however if you do that, please be extra careful what you write. You don't want to let anyone write just about anything in your public repo.